# Angular get request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a working angular form sitting inside an app (rails app). It sends a get request to a rails server.

The problem is that if this app receives a normal get request, it refreshes the page. However, when the request is sent via angular, I can see the request on the server, but the page is never refreshed. (I can use these get requests to get data back as well).

The question is how do I pass a get request in angular form, so that the server processes it normally, and refreshes the page?

html:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>get request</h3>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get</button>
</form>
```

app.js controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
  posts.factorySubmit();
};
```

app.js factory get function:

```
o.factorySubmit = function() { 
      $http.get('http://localhost:8080/clients');
};
```

--Side note - if I create a get request, with regular java script in the app, outside of the angular context, I get expected behavior, the page refreshes.

Comment: `$http.get` is an AJAX call, it won't refresh the page. But usually you don't want to reload the page in an angular app. Why do you want to reload it?

Comment: Do you want to reload to display the data from the GET ?

Comment: I need the server to process a bunch of logic that happens in rails, and reload the page with that new logic. Basically, I don't want to rewrite all that logic in angular..

Comment: I am able to load the data from GET and display it.. the problem is, I need the GET request to reload so that it hits the rails routing, runs through a bunch of logic and displays the page

Comment: Are you loading a partial from rails or are you redirecting?

Comment: I need the angular form, to direct the request to the rails router, so rails can run through the controller logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've wrapped your $http in a factory which is great practice.  What you're not doing is capturing the response.

```
o.factorySubmit = function() { 
      // Add a return here
      return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/clients'); // This call returns a promise
};
```

Then when you call this function...

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
  posts.factorySubmit().then(function(response) {
    $scope.requests = response.data;  // This is where you get your response
  },
  function(response) {
    // This is your error handling
  });
};
```

The cool thing about angular is that it will detect changes and update the page automatically.  It has a digest cycle that is called internally in response to changes.  Since you're using the built-in `$http` provider, it'll refresh when you update the `$scope` variables.

Comment: So, I put in your edits. The data that angular receives, gets refreshed. The problem is, it still doesn't refresh the page. It has to refresh in order for the app to hit the rails router and go through the logic, upon the get request :(

Comment: What does the rails logic need to do? Perhaps when you receive the call, you can post to perform any server-side logic.  Perhaps you're running into the same issue I ran into when I started mixing ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS.  It's a new way of thinking.

Comment: It receives params from the get request, parses data and draws charts

Comment: So, I will eventually turn it into a post request. But, won't I have the same problem with the post request? It will never hit the Rails router..

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you also need to update the chart on the page.  Is this being displayed on a canvas or img tag?  I'm going to assume that the rails router works similar to the ASP.NET routing system - i.e. it looks for urls in a particular format and routes it to server-side methods... is that correct?

Comment: The charts are through a couple of highcharts libraries.. the rails controller receives data and passes it to the view which is updated with new data.

Comment: Basically, if I could find some way of hitting that rails router with a post or get request, it would do everything I need.  Is there a way to create a reqular post request, without angular just directing it out to rails?

Comment: I'm going to have to look more into the rails routing system to understand what you mean.  If you can just type a url in the browser and have it hit rails routing then there's no reason you can't simply post directly from angular to rails.

Comment: Much appreciated. Well, that's the thing, angular is designed to not refresh with these requests. So, I need some way to get it to actually refresh.

Comment: @HoosierCoder, according to [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) the routing is just like in ASP.NET.  You can post directly to a route and have the route return just the data you need to update the chart.  Look at [this link](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js) showing you how to update the chart from angularjs.

Comment: So, the problem is that the returned data gets stuck in angular. So, none of the rails components get refreshed. For tables, I do it the way you are recommending. But for charting, all the logic is set up for rails to handle that. There are more controllers with diff rails logic, and I just need to hit them with angular form instead of a rails form and have the same behavior..

Comment: I'm working on a demo already over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DhLhxx9e67KRrbFD1xfm?p=preview) to show how this can be updated.

Comment: Done.  Take a look:  http://plnkr.co/edit/DhLhxx9e67KRrbFD1xfm?p=preview

Comment: Nice, but the thing is, that still doesn't get a page refresh, and all the logic stays in angular. So, I would have to change all of the application functionality to be in angular. Eventually, this is the answer, but again I need the rails page to refresh on get request.

Comment: The logic to calculate the data (which is what I assume happens on the rails side) can stay on the rails side.  You just need to think about what has to "respond to changes" and let angular handle those parts.  `$window.location.reload();` I believe should just refresh the page.  Here's an example where the chart is converted to a directive.  There's also a reload page button.  http://plnkr.co/edit/aymngVE2Wjz3jmuIQLMO?p=preview

Comment: I wanted to clarify one more thing:  suppose you have a rails endpoint like `GET` **/clients/new** and it calculates the number of new clients each month. I'm proposing that you make your get call to this endpoint from angular and let it simply process and return the data as JSON.  If you're using it to return and update the views, then you'll run into the same problem I had when I started with ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS.  They don't mesh well.  Now I use ASP.NET WebAPI for the REST calls and AngularJS for handling the views. It's a better separation of concerns.

Comment: I agree with everything you are saying. My problem is I just don't have the time to recode an entire application and only use rails as an API. So, I just need to find a way to trigger rails from an angular form, or maybe just use a jquery form for this portion.

Comment: I understand.  Did you see my comment about `$window.location.reload();`?  It's in the last plnkr as well.

Comment: I have.. but won't that just reload the page as opposed to using the params from the form and then reloading with the correct logic?

Comment: If you've posted first, then the page can reload with fresh data.  So: post, let it do your server-side updates, then reload the page.  I suppose another way you could do this would be to just create a form and post the actual values - i.e. when they click on the submit button, let the form post back and don't use angular to intercept.

Comment: So, I got the `location.reload()` to work, but after the get request, it just refreshed the initial page without passing params. As a temporary solution, I'm just using a form without angular and throwing in onchange of form `this.form.submit();`  to mimic angular behavior.  Then, slowly recoding all the logic to angular as you suggested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is by design supposed to not refresh the page as it is built for Single Page Applications. If you want to manually refresh the page, use

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){
  posts.factorySubmit().success(function(){
   $route.refresh();
  });
};
```

In the success function of your `$get` request. Remember to inject `$route` into your controller.

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason as soon as I inject the $route, it breaks the app. This controller code look correct? `.controller('MainCtrl', [
 '$scope',
 '$route',
 'posts',
 function($scope, $route, posts){

   $scope.posts = posts.posts; 

   $scope.submitForm = function(){
    posts.factorySubmit().success(function(){
     $route.refresh();
    });
   };
 }
])`

Comment: According to the $http docs, .success() is now deprecated -- use the standard .then() callback instead
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http